# Pgadmin 4 cannot connect to server at port 5432 timeout

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

Here I have installed pgadmin 4 on windows 10. Trying to connect to the client server at port 5432. Couldn't able to understand why it is not connecting to it. Here is the error message

[image]

I try to do the troubleshoot it says it is "NOT LISTENING ", also configured but still see the same error message

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Is the postgres **server** (BTW, you seem to be confused by the term "server" as opposed to the term "client") started? Are you sure you can reach the IP address you masked? Are you sure the server is listening to port 5432 (see file postgres.conf)?

Comment: I actually forgot to ask if you checked the server is configured to accept connection from your computer (see file pg_hba.conf). I do not think you would get a connection timeout error if it was not configured correctly but I could be wrong and suggest you check that part too.